# Coding Bat Recursion exercise (java)

Tags: java, string, recursion

How can I solve this problem recursively instead of using the replace method? I'm trying to get better a recursive methods.

Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) a new string where all the lowercase 'x' chars have been changed to 'y' chars.

```
changeXY("codex") → "codey"
changeXY("xxhixx") → "yyhiyy"
changeXY("xhixhix") → "yhiyhiy"
```

I cheated and solved it this way and tried to look at the source code for Java String method replace but I didn't understand it. Here's my method.

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  int i = 0;
  String changedStr = str.replace("x","y");


  if (len == 0)
    return str;

  return changedStr;

}
```

Any ideas on how to do it a recursive way?

Here's a bonus exercise that I didn't know how to do either. Thank you for your help!!!

Given a string, compute recursively a new string where all the 'x' chars have been removed.

```
noX("xaxb") → "ab"
noX("abc") → "abc"
noX("xx") → ""
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Besides your non-recursive solution.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but couldn't you do `if (str.contains("x")) {String result = changeXY(str.substring(1,str.length())}`? And changeXY just looks at the first char to change it?

Comment: @jrubins no I haven't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursion is almost always composed of two things:

A condition to stop the recursion.

**assuming** we can solve a smaller problem, how to solve the current one using that assumption.

```
public String changeXY(String str) {

  // when to stop
  if (str.length() == 0){
    return str;
  }

  // handle the "special case" using an assumption we can solve str.substring(1)
  if (str.charAt(0) == 'x'){
    return 'y' + changeXY(str.substring(1));
  }
  // handle the "simple" case using an assumption we can solve str.substring(1)
  return str.charAt(0) + changeXY(str.substring(1));
}
```

Other exercises are very easy once you realize how this works.

Comment: Thank you!! I agree once you understand the concept other string recursion methods like this are easy. I usually go through the debugger on Eclipse to understand things better. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'll give you the check in a few minutes

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is based on 2 things :
1- base case : that will stop the method from calling itself by certain condition 
2- operation : what you want to do by this method + calling the method again with changing its argument to reach the base case.
In this case you have to do the following

```
public String changeXY(String string){

    string = string.toLowerCase();
    if(string.length()==0)
    { 
        return string;
    }
    else if (str.charAt(0) == 'x')
    {
        return 'y' + changeXY(str.substring(1));
    }

    return str.charAt(0) + changeXY(str.substring(1)); 
}
```

Comment: How come changeXY(str.substring(1)) doesn't give an outOfBounds error if there aren't any more indices?

Answer (score 2):

pseudocode:

```
  changeXY(input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) return "";
    head = "firstChar"(input);
    tail = "theRest"(input);
    return (head == 'x' ? 'y' : head) + changeXY(tail);
  }


  noX(input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) return "";
    head = "firstChar"(input);
    tail = "theRest"(input);
    return (head == 'x' ? '' : head) + noX(tail);
  }
```

All you have to do is to implement or call proper Java API instead of "firstChar" and "theRest". I believe it will be piece of cake ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hope my answer explains everything :)

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
  if (str.length() == 0) return ""; // return empty string if we reached the end of string
  String count = str.substring(0,1); // get the current string
  if (str.substring(0, 1).equals("x")) count = "y"; // if its x then replace it with y 
  // attach it to our final string and make recursive call passing string past the read character
  return count + changeXY(str.substring(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First exercise:

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
      int len = str.length();
      String changedStr = "";
      for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
          if(str.charAt(i) == 'x'){
              changedStr+="y";
          }else{
              changedStr+=str.charAt(i);
          }
      }

      if (len == 0)
        return str;

      return changedStr;

}
```

When it's a "x", changes to y until the string is terminated.

The second exercise is even easier: just change the `changedStr+="y"` part to the `continue` java instruction.

However, this code is not beginner-friendly. It requires you to have a knowledge about loops in general. I really recommend you to check the other answers, if you're a student. They're far easier to understand and get a grip of.

Comment: Thank you. I get loops but I haven't practiced recursion at all so I'm trying to solve this exercises without them.

Comment: This is not recursion, and therefore does not answer the question "How can I solve this problem recursively...". Furthermore, it provides inaccurate information; this is NOT "recursion in a for-loop", as you claim it is. I'm not trying to be rude or anything, but this answer contains fallacies and inaccuracies.

Comment: @CodyS I'm sorry, what gets me here is the concept of recursion: `Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way`. I always miss the 'self' part. I'll fix the details, but keep my answer here, unless the author wants me to delete it.
Again, thanks by the comment!

Comment: no sweat @g.carvalho97 you were only trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into recursion only where there is 'x' in the given string.
Do recursive calls until all 'x' are changed to 'y'.

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
  if(str.contains("x")){
    int idx = str.indexOf("x");
    return changeXY(str.substring(0,idx) + "y" + str.substring(idx+1, str.length()));
  }
  else return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

python code

```
def changeXY(s):
    if len(s) == 1 and s == 'x' : return 'y'
    if len(s) == 1 : return s
    char,sub = s[0:1],s[1:]       
    if char == 'x' :  char = 'y'  
    return char + changeXY(sub)
```

Comment: This question is relates to Java, not Python.

Answer (score -1):

First exercise...

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0) return str;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'x') return 'y' + changeXY(str.substring(1, str.length()));
  return str.charAt(0) + changeXY(str.substring(1, str.length()));
}
```

Second exercise...

```
public String noX(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0) return str;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'x') return "" + noX(str.substring(1));
  return str.charAt(0) + noX(str.substring(1)); 
}
```